# UIPageControl in Landscape Orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uipagecontrol

I've gone through the Apple's Sample Code using UIPageControl and ScrollView togther. I've created the same using viewControllers instead of Views. Now when i change the orientation from Potrait to LandScape, the ScrollView changes its orientation but UIPageControl remain in same position :( and instead of changing page in horizontal Swipe,it changes the page in the Vertical swipe

I want the UIPageControl to change page on horizontal swipe and in LandScape mode.

is it possible??? :(

Answer (score 0):

I got it now... :)

The UIPageControl app uses window.xib, I created a new app with the same code applied on the UIViewController and it worked..

Also dun forget to turn **vertical bounce property  to "NO"**, to make it slide horizontally..

:)